# manga where mc had his lover stolen by the hero

Tags: story-identification, manga

mc and the saint as children made a promise to date each other when they grow older but when mc sees the saint she was getting married to the hero. I know that it is a manga .

Comment: This needs more detail. Do you recall the appearances of any of the characters? Or what the hero and saint were doing? Or what happened after he saw this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Sono Mono Michi Ni](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=140584)* as per [Manga where the guy’s fiancée goes out with the hero. He sadly isolates himself in the forest, which is the most dangerous place](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243456/)

> The fiancée of the main character (Wazu) leaves him for the Hero. Devastated, Wazu runs off to a dangerous mountain full of S-ranked monsters. There, he befriends a cute, chibi dragon creature. Also, the voice of a goddess starts speaking to him from within his status card, and informs him that he has a special "Bizarre Eater" skill, which allows him to get stronger by eating anything that is higher ranked than he is.

[image: Wazu proposing]

[image: Hero taking the girl]

Comment: yes it is it thank you